# Why does my data from SQL table delete after I run this code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, mariadb

I have this code that I want to run and it's connected to my database and it uses to show the values on the table but every time I do an UPDATE query.

It updates the rest of the row with zeros except the one I've chosen. I want to keep my numbers on the row but only update the one that i chose but I can't figure it out how to!

I initialized the table with a row with Zeros (0s) and then with my web page application I want to change those values.

But if I have another value on the rest of the columns and I want to change this one, the rest of the values go to zero (the initial state of the table) (I don't know how to explain it better I think)

```
<?php 
                      $showData = ("SELECT * FROM horario");
                      if ($new_user_activity['data'] == 'Seg' ) {
                          $segHora = $new_user_activity['horas'];
                      }
                          $sql = ("UPDATE horario SET seg=$segHora WHERE id=1");
                          if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
                            echo("ERRO NA QUERY" );
                          }
                          else {
                            if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
                              $sqlData = mysqli_query($conn,$showData);
                              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlData,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                              echo($row['seg']);
                              }     

                        }

                        }

            ?>
```

Its expected to keep my values from the other columns on the same row!

[image: PICTURE OF WHAT IS HAPPENING TO THE DATABASE]

Comment: Please provide data example and expected results.

Comment: And don't provide them as image!

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras I added to the text a picture ! can you see it ?

Comment: OK i will try to explain it the examples i need and the expected results:

What happens is that  (as shown on the image) i have a table with some entries . Only Ter has the value 8. and the rest have 0 as a Value.

On my webApplication i change the value of Seg to 123 and when i submit it it automatically changes the value of Ter to 0 without i ask for it ! is it clear?

Comment: Why are you doing the same update query twice?

Comment: @charlietfl im just doing this one on the code for each column.

$sql = ("UPDATE horario SET seg=$segHora WHERE id=1");

Comment: Ive tested the Update query on the SQL terminal and it works fine. only issue is with this code

Comment: You do it twice...once in each `if()`

Comment: that was only for test purposes. but ive took it out and it still happens the same

Comment: right before you execute the query, try echo $sql, to see the exact query you are sending ?

Comment: the error must be related to the value of $segHora

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé it give me this: "UPDATE horario SET seg=8 WHERE id=18" 
Where the last 8 is from the table itself

Comment: ive printed and its suposed to be the value that im passing to the table the right way! probably there is another way of updating the table that i dont know

Comment: can you execute DESCRIBE horario in your SQL terminal ?

Comment: +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tipoHorario | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seg         | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ter         | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
Its something like this

Comment: Can i send it to you in private? probably its better because of the identation

Comment: as you have told it is working fine if you run an update query directly on SQL. but you are facing this error when you run this query via PHP. I think there is another query which is running before your update query and making all the columns null before your update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code you've shown is **not** responsible for resetting the row. Something else must be doing it. There is another update somewhere, possibly a trigger on the database, but it's not coming from the code sample you've posted.

Regarding your code, there are several things wrong, which others have already pointed out. I would like to add a couple more

1. Ensure you SANITIZE your data before inserting it in MySQL. Check out PDO and [bindparam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), for starters. Short of that, use (int) to cast the variable to an integer.
2. The update should only happen if there is new user activity.

Code:

```
 if ($new_user_activity['data'] == 'Seg') {
     $segHora = (int)$new_user_activity['horas'];
     $sql = ("UPDATE horario SET seg=$segHora WHERE id=1");

     if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
         echo ("ERRO NA QUERY");
         return; // or exit, if this is not a function
     }
 }

 $showData = ("SELECT * FROM horario");
 $sqlData = mysqli_query($conn, $showData);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlData, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo ($row['seg']);
 }
```

Comment: This acctually helped and the problem got solved! Thank you so much.

Im still very new at SQL so im trying my best ! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. You will keep making mistakes, even if you are a master of your trade.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the table is resetting all of the values in every column at each query. This might meant that every time you run your code, the database connection that you have set up first updates every column with zeros, and then inserts your new data. I would check your connection script.

Comment: $servername = " ....MY IP...";
    $username = "...MY USERNAME";
    $password = "... MY PASSWORD";
    $dbname = "....MY DBNAME,...";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


    // Check connection
    if ($conn -> connect_error){
      die("DATABASE CONNECTION FAILED: " . $conn -> connect_error);
    }
    echo "<h6 class='connected'> CONNECTED TO DATABASE</h6>";

    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"UTF8");

Comment: im just creating that on top of the page!

Comment: Please provide the code that initializes the database with zeros. And why the initialization?

Comment: its just a simple insert when created the database , something like INSERT INTO horario(...) Values(..0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

Comment: i did that because i just ddnt want it to start with null! because at the end i have to sum the values of the columns to give a total